# If every non-empty open set of $X$ is dense in $X$, then if $C$ is an arbitrary own closed of $X$, then interior part of $C$ is empty.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ a topological space. I have to prove it:
If every non-empty open set of $X$ is dense in $X$, then if $C$ is an arbitrary own closed of $X$, then interior part of $C$ is empty.
I tried to prove it but I don’t arrive at corrected conclusion.

Comment: What if $C=X$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If interior of $C$ is non empty, then it's a non-empty open set, then it is dense, then closure of $C$ is $X$, then closure of $C$ is $X$, then $C = X$ (as closed subset is closure of itself).